# How do I find the sum value of an array of objects in a loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I'm not sure if the wording of my question is accurate based on my description of the problem so please edit if it can be more accurate.

I am trying to build a stamp duty calculator to improve my JS, i have an array of objects with different "bands" and "percents" which I am using to calculate the tax based on a users input. I have attached a image for better understanding

[image]

I am displaying the amount of tax for each band in a table and I am trying to find the total tax by finding the sum of all values in the "TAX" column.

Currently it is just displaying the highest value.

I have tried all i can thing off and nothing has worked, how can I fix this?

here is my code,

```
 $(function (jQuery) {
     
     (function stampDutyCalculator() {
     
     var taxbands = [
         {
             min: 0,
             max: 125000,
             percent: 0
         },
         {
             min: 125000,
             max: 250000,
             percent: 0.02
         },
         {
             min: 250000,
             max: 925000,
             percent: 0.05
         },
         {
             min: 925000,
             max: 1500000,
             percent: 0.1
         },
         {
             min: 1500000,
             max: null,
             percent: 0.12
         }
     ];
         
     var secondTaxbands = [
         {
             min: 0,
             max: 125000,
             percent: 0.03
         },
         {
             min: 125000,
             max: 250000,
             percent: 0.05
         },
         {
             min: 250000,
             max: 925000,
             percent: 0.08
         },
         {
             min: 925000,
             max: 1500000,
             percent: 0.13
         },
         {
             min: 1500000,
             max: null,
             percent: 0.15
         }
     ];
         
     var tableRow = "<tr><td>{taxband}</td><td>{percent}</td><td>{taxable}</td><td class='tax'>{TAX}</td></tr>", 
         table = $("#explained-table"),
         results = $("#results"),
         effectiveRate = $("#effective-rate");
        
         $('#calculate').on('click', function calculateButton() {
             if ($("#input-value").val() !== '') {  
                calculateStampDuty();
             }
         });

         function calculateStampDuty() {

            var bands = taxbands,        
                userInput = parseInt($("#input-value").val(), 10), 
                row;

            if ($('#second-home').is(':checked')) { 
                bands = secondTaxbands;
            }
                 
            if (table.length) {  
                table.find("tr:gt(0)").remove(); 
            }
             
            var taxableSum = function (x, y) { 
                var maxBand = (x !== null) ? Math.min(x, userInput) : maxBand = userInput; 
                return maxBand - y;
            },
                TAX = function (taxablesum, x) { 
                return (taxablesum * x).toFixed(2);
            },
                effectiverate = function(tax) {
                    return Math.round(tax / userInput * 100).toFixed(1);
            },  
                numberWithCommas = function (x) {
                var parts = x.toString().split(".");
                parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
                return parts.join(".");
            };
             
                        for (var i = 0; i < bands.length; i++) { //for loop to loop through array of objects
        
            var min = bands[i].min, //variables to be used as arguments in functions above, not best practice to declare functions in loop
                max = bands[i].max,
                pct = bands[i].percent,
                taxablesum = taxableSum(max, min),
                tax = TAX(taxablesum, pct),
                eRate = effectiverate(tax);

            if (max !== null) { //replaces template tags with min, max and percent values in object
                row = tableRow.replace("{taxband}", "£" + min + " - " + "£" + max).replace("{percent}", (pct * 100) + "%");
            } else {
                row = tableRow.replace("{taxband}", "£" + min + "+").replace("{percent}", (pct * 100) + "%"); //used for last taxband
            } 
            
            if (taxablesum < 0) {
                row = row.replace("{taxable}", "£" + 0 + ".00").replace("{TAX}", "£" + 0 + ".00");
            }   else if (userInput > 1500000) {
                    row = row.replace("{taxable}", "£" + numberWithCommas(taxablesum)).replace("{TAX}", "£" + numberWithCommas(tax));
                    results.text("£" + numberWithCommas(tax));
                    effectiveRate.text(eRate + "%");
            }   else if (userInput > 925000) {
                    row = row.replace("{taxable}", "£" + numberWithCommas(taxablesum)).replace("{TAX}", "£" + numberWithCommas(tax));
                    results.text("£" + numberWithCommas(tax));
                    effectiveRate.text(eRate + "%");
            }   else if (userInput > 250000) {
                    row = row.replace("{taxable}", "£" + numberWithCommas(taxablesum)).replace("{TAX}", "£" + numberWithCommas(tax));
                    results.text("£" + numberWithCommas(tax));
                    effectiveRate.text(eRate + "%");
            }   else if (userInput > 125000) {
                    row = row.replace("{taxable}", "£" + numberWithCommas(taxablesum)).replace("{TAX}", "£" + numberWithCommas(tax));
                    results.text("£" + numberWithCommas(tax));
                    effectiveRate.text(eRate + "%");
            }   else {
                    row = row.replace("{taxable}", "£" + userInput).replace("{TAX}", "£" + numberWithCommas(tax));
                    results.text("£" + (numberWithCommas(tax) * 0));
                    effectiveRate.text(eRate * 0 + "%");
            }
            
            table.append(row);
            
            console.log(Number(tax) );
        }
         }
         
     }());
 });
```

EDIT
here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/p6c1w5r3/

some of buttons functionality is not completed yet,  I wanted to get the calculations correct first

Comment: could you prepare this into a jsfiddle?

Comment: I included in the question now

Comment: Can you explain the question? As of now, it seems the functionality is fine.

Comment: My question is how can I find the sum of all the values in the "TAX" column

Comment: Ok. I guessed it correct then. Give me some time to check the code then.

Comment: Move `tax = TAX(taxablesum, pct)`  line out of the loop. Your tax variable is being recreated every time, causing the last value to be lost. Instead declare variable before the loop, then use += to add the tax inside the loop.

Comment: Or add an extra variable called total tax, and then do `totaltax += tax `somewhere in the loop.

Comment: wouldn't that cause an issue with scope since the pct variable is defined in the loop. I tried but it returned NaN

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112899/discussion-between-jitendra-garg-and-sai).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the solution, after playing around with it a bit, the main problem was rooted in the taxablesum function returning negative numbers which was resolved with this piece of code

```
return Math.max(0, maxBand - min);
```

here is a link to the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nnyawjob/

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/p6c1w5r3/7/

Basically we create another variable outside the loop called `totalTax`. Then inside the loop we add the tax value to this variable.

Finally, you should not set the label text every time, instead set it once at the end.

Oh btw, your tax calculation returns weird values when amount is less than 20000.

Answer (score -1):

The error seems to be that in your tax calculation function you are receiving a negative value ( i didn't look deeper into it to check why thats the case ) but you can avoid that with this little helper function: `Math.abs(x)`

I have updated your js fiddle and it seems to work now (at least its displaying some tax value)

```
TAX = function (taxablesum, x) { //takes taxablesum function as parameater to calculate overall tax
    return (Math.abs(taxablesum) * x).toFixed(2);
},
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p6c1w5r3/1/

**EDIT**

this update contains a console log of the total_tax (the summed up taxes)
Hope this helps

https://jsfiddle.net/p6c1w5r3/4/

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. It returns the last tax amount.

Comment: ah so you want to display the sum off all calculated tax values right?

Comment: correct, btw I wasn't sure about the negative values either thanks for that fix